# Setting up boost filesystem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, boost

I've been having serious problems trying to set up boost. I must have installed and uninstalled the libraries a dozen times. In my most recent attempt, I followed these instructions:

1. Download the zip and unzip it.
2. Get the prebuilt jam executable and unzip it. Put that directory in your path.
   (Edit Path by using Control Panel...System..Advanced....Environemnt Variables)
3. Open Visual Studio command prompt. Browse to boost directory. 
    Run: bjam "-sTOOLS=vc-8_0" install

The main reason I'm trying to use boost is for boost/filesystem yet nothing is working. I know this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470840/problem-linking-boost-filesystem-library-in-microsoft-visual-c), but it only resulted in more errors..

Please Help!

Comment: Can you tell us the specific error you are encountering?

Comment: We're not psychics. We don't know what errors you're getting (either when running bjam or when using the installer, or when compiling your program to use Boost.Filesystem.

"nothing is working", and "resulted in more errors" isn't very helpful. If nothing is truly working, my guess is that the universe is coming to an end. I can't think of anything else that would cause symptoms of "nothing is working".

Comment: until you give us some information about your problem, I see no reason not to downvote the question. ("the question is unclear or not useful")

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [installer](http://www.boostpro.com/download)?

Comment: Yes I have. My program wouldn't compile though.

Comment: Then you're going to have to give more information than that.  I doubt your compilation issue has anything to do with Boost itself but rather a) how you're linking to boost b) how you've written your code (should it compile in the first place?) and c) are there conflicting libraries you're linking made by dumbass third party snakeoil salesmen vendors.  Not that I've had, um, much experience with "c."

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try the installer mentioned above.  Then make sure that you setup your include path and library search path in the project settings.

Also, try a very simple "hello world using boost" type of program to see if it is your project setup or your use of boost that is the issue.